# Apache: No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My website is on apache server.
Path: `/var/www/example.com/public_html`

I am trying to access file in `public_html` folder.

**PHP**

```
require('/application/config/development/dev_config.php');
```

**ERROR**

> PHP Warning:  require(/application/config/development/dev_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/example.com/public_html/index.php on line 53

When I tried to do this:

```
require('application/config/development/dev_config.php');
```

It's running fine. **But, I used forward slash in all over the place in my project.** Is there any way to change this setting in `.htaccess` file? so, I can access it by using `/`.

**Apache Config File**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: as i know `require` don't depend on the apache , also you can use find and replace with your editor it will take a time but it's better this way

Comment: BTW some IDE can search the whole project to find and replace

Comment: `/` is a general term. It could be in each page.

Comment: ofc you won't search for `/` you will search for `require('/application/` and replace with `require('application/` idk exactly what should be done but it will be something like that

Answer (score 1):

**Apache and PHP Understand `/` Differently**

**Apache** views your *web root* as your root folder (`/var/www/example.com/public_html/`), whereas **PHP** is able to access your *entire system* (so '/' means '/'). That means that while

```
<a href="/home.php">...</a>
```

really means `/var/www/example.com/public_html/home.php`,

```
header('Location:/home.php');
```

would mean a `home.php` file in the root directory of your server's system.

**Solution**

The easiest (IMHO) way to avoid typing out the entire web directory structure when indicating a web file to PHP is to use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable. This queries Apache to find the path to the web directory root, and you can add the rest of the file path as though you were talking to Apache. For example:

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home.php');
```

would be understood by PHP to mean `/var/www/example.com/public_html/home.php`.

Answer (score 0):

/application does not exist, the actual folder you want is:

```
/var/www/example.com/public_html/application/config/development/dev_config.php
```

By beginning with / you are telling the system to look at the very root path of your file system (where/var is for example).

The reason application/config/development/dev_config.php works is as you are calling the folder relative to the current folder as you are already in public_html

Comment: Yeah.. I know all this. I just need solution for that if there is any. Because it's very hard to change everywhere in project. Actually, I am moving current website to different server.